# Limit and expectation of bounded random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be two stochastic processes with $X_n \leq 1$ and $Y_n \leq 1$ for all $n$ (not independent). Further, suppose $$ \frac{E (X_n)}{q^n} \to 1 \quad \text{and} \quad Y_n \to 1 \text{ a.s.}$$

I want to know whether $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{E(X_n Y_n)}{q^n} = 1 $$
holds. Note that $X_n/q^n$ not necessarily converges to $1$ a.s.

Comment: You can try $X_n=Y_n$ and $q=1$.

Comment: @Michael It works in that case, doesn't it? By dominated convergence $E (X_n Y_n) \to 1$?

Comment: How are you applying dominated convergence to conclude $E[X_nY_n]\rightarrow 1$? There is no dominating function.